# #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'MICROSECOND'

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

I wanted to create an event to do something every 5 seconds like this  :

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS event_test ;
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT event_test ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND_MICROSECOND
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR_MINUTE
DO
BEGIN
CALL pro_rand_lucy() ;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

but it seems like it sin't supported and I get the bellow error saying 'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'MICROSECOND'' :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKtQd.png)

I use Wamp localhost
MySQL Version: 5.7.31

can you please recommend me a substitute for microsecond or another version of Wamp that does support it .

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a five second interval, just use `SECOND`:

```
CREATE EVENT event_test ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
...
```

`SECOND_MICROSECOND` suggests you want to use a value like `5.050033` - and as you have discovered, it's not supported yet.